# Memory overlap in DS-5 when implementing code for arm Cortex-A9

Tags: c, arm, neon, ds-5

I am already stuck for many days trying to implement a code in DS-5, targeting Cortex-A9 and using NEON SIMD intrinsics. I managed to execute some small programs through the debugger, but when I am trying to allocate memory bigger than 256KB I always get a message

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   L6221E: Execution region ZI_DATA with Execution range [0x80001674,0x800417d0) overlaps with Execution region ARM_LIB_HEAP with Execution range [0x80040000,0x80080000). CPUTest2017RE           C/C++ Problem

The memory map is scheduled by a scatter file as follows

```
 ;*******************************************************
 ; Copyright (c) 2011-2014 ARM Ltd.  All rights reserved.
 ;*******************************************************

 ; Scatter-file for Cortex-A9 bare-metal example on Versatile Express

 ; This scatter-file places application code, data, stack and heap at      suitable addresses in the memory map.
 ; Using a scatter-file with ARM_LIB_STACKHEAP eliminates the need to set stack-limit or heap-base in the debugger.

 ; Versatile Express with Cortex-A9 has 1GB SDRAM at 0x60000000 to      0x9FFFFFFF, which this scatter-file uses.


SDRAM 0x80000000 0x10000000
{
VECTORS +0
{
    * (VECTORS, +FIRST)     ; Vector table and other (assembler) startup code
    * (InRoot$$Sections)    ; All (library) code that must be in a root region
}

RO_CODE +0
{ * (+RO-CODE) }            ; Application RO code (.text)

RO_DATA +0
{ * (+RO-DATA) }            ; Application RO data (.constdata)

RW_DATA +0
{ * (+RW) }                 ; Application RW data (.data)

ZI_DATA +0
{ * (+ZI) }                 ; Application ZI data (.bss)

ARM_LIB_HEAP  0x80040000 EMPTY  0x00040000 ; Application heap
{ }

ARM_LIB_STACK 0x80090000 EMPTY -0x00010000 ; Application (SVC mode) stack
{ }

IRQ_STACK     0x800A0000 EMPTY -0x00010000 ; IRQ mode stack
{ }

TTB           0x80100000 EMPTY 0x4000      ; Level-1 Translation Table for      MMU
{ }
}
```

[image]
So my problem is that when I allocate memory to pass a 512x512 (.bdat format) Image this allocation happens in ZI_DATA and not in SDRAM that is free. I tried near every configuration and either I get the error above either the debugger stuck on pending... What is the problem here??

PS: the same code was running on Cortex-A8 and older version of DS-5 but for some reason the Cortex-A8 debugger is not working with the newest version of DS-5.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that your bss data is going out of range and into the HEAP section. You can try a few things ...

```
1) Limit the maximum bss section so the error will be more clear
2) Move Heap section on a higher address 
3) generate a map file which has all the section sizes. to see what is taking so much space in the bss section and maybe moving that to some other section.
```

The fact that the same code works for A8 is not really helpful because the libraries are different and so are the code sections...  I have been there and it does'nt feels good :)

Comment: I tried to move the memory limits in order to compile the code but later on the emulator stuck  ... The weird thing is that the example I am using is a ready to use example that comes with DS-5.

Comment: have you checked the map file ? can you paste that file to any pastebin so that I can see